# Javascript | Enter key first time should press a button, second time should press a label or url

Tags: javascript

First time we press keyboard enter key should execute button(id="botonCorregir"). But the second time we press enter key should execute url().
I use cont, for the first time execute one part of the javascript code, and after when de cont value is 1, execute the second part of javascript code.
For some mistake, it doesn´t work.

thanks!

HTML:

```
<input id="respuestaUsuario"></input>

<button id="botonCorregir">Reply</button>
<a id="enlaceSiguiente" href="nextQuestion.html">Next question</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
var cont=0;
if(cont==0){
//Should enter the first press of enter
      var input = document.getElementById("respuestaUsuario"); 
    console.log('input: ', input)
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById("botonCorregir").click();
      }
    });
    cont++;
}else{
//Should enter the second press of enter
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById("enlaceSiguiente").click();
      }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in the code.

You are assigning the event based on the value of **cont** so always will have that functionality. Javascript does not re-interpret the code once the value of **cont** is changed.
I mean, Javascript check only one time the condition:

```
if(cont==0){}
```

This is a solution that works:

```
var cont=0;
var input = document.getElementById('respuestaUsuario');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if(!cont){
      alert('uno');
      document.getElementById("botonCorregir").click();
      cont++;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("enlaceSiguiente").click();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were on the right track, but the problem is that your Javascript only gets executed once. So, the else case will never be triggered. I refactored your code to use the check in the event listener:

```
        var cont = 0;

        var input = document.getElementById("respuestaUsuario");
        input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (cont == 0) {
              cont++;

              document.getElementById("botonCorregir").click();
            } else {
              document.getElementById("enlaceSiguiente").click();
            }
          }
        });
```

I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/RwWOOpY?editors=1111) for you to check out.